# Which service to use when running app for longer time (Android)?

Tags: android, memory-management, service, android-workmanager, foreground-service

I want to run my app for a longer time in the background, it needs to get the user location every 15 min and send it to the server. I went through different concepts regarding android like **Foreground Service** and **Work Manager**. Some custom OS like MIUI doesn't allow this as it puts some restriction with the battery usage. Which is the best approach to solve my problem?

Comment: Work Manager....

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to apply for the resident of the background process through the manufacturer’s developer channel. For these customized OS, the background process running control is very strict, especially for this long-term application of positioning information in the background. Power consumption behavior

Comment: For normal stock android devices, what kind of a service can I use?